# Probability Mass Function Understanding What To Look For!

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

**Problem:**
For which value of $\alpha$ is the function $p_i=\frac{(\alpha+1)(i-\alpha)+2}{120}$ of $\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$ a p.m.f?

My understanding is that $p_i=1$ and that $i=\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$, but trying to solve for $\alpha$ seems overly complicated.

I tried using a formula simplifier on another website and got the following to solve for $\alpha$:
$$\alpha=-\frac{1-i+ \sqrt{-472+2i}}{2},-\frac{1-i- \sqrt{-472+2i}}{2}$$

But then of course it broke my calculator because the value inside the $sqrt{}$ is negative. So then I tried understanding how to fix the negative $sqrt{}$ and it took me to the next step of trying to understand if this is a radical expression and only when the $i$ is replaced with a number can it be distilled down. However, even then it creates an $i$ out front of the $sqrt$ and I don't know if that $i$ is the same as the $i$ in my equation. Example: $2i\sqrt{118}$.

So at this point, I am sufficiently lost, but my thoughts are that what I'm solving for is to see which of the numbers $i=\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$ is the correct number. What constitutes the right answer? Is it if $\alpha$ is a whole number?

Can someone help me understand the whole question/problem?  I fear I am in the weeds on this one.

Thank you

Comment: First simplification - use another letter $(k)$ instead of $(i)$ for the index.  Second $\sum_{k=1}^{10} p_k=1$, not $p_k=1$.  If $\alpha$ is not real, it looks wrong.

Comment: "My understanding is that $p_i = 1$" Why do you say that? That's not correct.

Comment: I am deep into an online course that is taking me to mathematical places I've never been.  I am trying my best to answer the first line of this post which is the problem.  If none of what I say below that problem statement makes sense it's because I have no clue how to solve this and that is my best attempt.  Help me step by step.  Also herb steinberg I'm still not understanding how what you said helps me get to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- $i$ here is a index, not $\sqrt{-1}$
- You want $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(\alpha+1)(i-\alpha)+2}{120}=1$ as this is a sum of all the probabilities
- When finding the sum, $i$ should not appear in the result as it is a bound variable

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(\alpha+1)(i-\alpha)+2}{120} \\ = \frac{2-\alpha^2-\alpha}{120}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}1 + \frac{\alpha+1}{120} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}i \\ = \frac{2-\alpha^2-\alpha}{120}\times 10 + \frac{\alpha+1}{120} \times 55 $$

- Simplifying this and setting this equal to $1$ will give you a quadratic equation with two real roots for $\alpha$.
- You should check each potential solution to ensure they give probabilities for $p_i$: in particular the probabilities should be non-negative.  One works and the other does not.

Comment: I would say one of $\frac32$ and $3$ is correct and the other wrong.  What are the $10$ values of $p_i$ when you use them? Do they add up to $1$? Are they non-negative? Meanwhile $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=10$ while $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55$.

Comment: I was incorrect! Sorry.  I didn't think to try the 3/2 for my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!